# Facebook Workplace webhook call back url fixing

Tags: azure, facebook-webhooks, facebook-workplace

I have two Azure web apps services and both have been configured similarly.
When I pass the callback URL to the workplace webhook, one of them is working whereas the other is not. I have verified the verify token, access token, and they are both correct.

I get the fail message: "We could not verify the webhook callback. Make sure your webserver is listening and reachable through the specified callback url." when I pass this URL along with the token:
`https://<xxx>.azurewebsites.net/webhook`

Comment: Calling `https://.azurewebsites.net/webhook` in my browser, it automatically removes the leading dot, and then tells me, _“azurewebsites.net’s server DNS address could not be found”_

Comment: U alos have to use your web app name

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: why are you calling this url . What are you trying to do here in browser?

Comment: I am just trying to understand your problem in relation to my problem

Comment: Facebook says it can not reach the callback URL you specified. So I did a quick “test” in my browser to see if it is reachable _for me_ - and since it isn’t, because this domain name can not be resolved by the DNS, there is a good chance that the exact same issue occurs, when Facebook tries to reach it ...

Comment: I have another azure web app with different name and the same DNS which works fine.

Comment: You're going to want to add more details to your question for others to help you with it.  As written, it's not really clear what could be going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable "*Always On*" via the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com) to make your app running reliably.

[image]

Comment: Again I have another web app service which works just fine and its in the same Azure portal which does not have the 'Always On' as ON but it still works fine.

Comment: Since it would require us to move from a free tier to a pricing tier , we need a valid reason to do it and since the call back url is working for another similar app without this setting set to ON, we cant find the justified reason to do so.